# code for removing utf8 characters does not work on php 5.3.3

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm using this code:

```
$technical   = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $technical);
```

It works good on >php7 but it does not work on php5.3.3

It's the same code, is there any replace solution for version 5.3.3?

Comment: Why such an old version?

Comment: that is the client-server so I need to start the script on his server, on mine server I have PHP 7

Comment: why you should code in the same version as where it's living^

Comment: generally, older versions of language do no support all of the features of a newer version.

What error message are you getting?

Since all Unicode characters can be represented in UTF-8, removing them will leave you with an empty string.

Comment: This is such an old version that I can't with clear conscience suggest you any solution other than just upgrade to PHP 7

Comment: there is no error message, code just don't work

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex:

```
$regex = "/((?: [\x00-\x7F]|[\xC0-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|[\xE0-\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|[\xF0-\xF7][\x80-\xBF]{3}){1,100})| ./x";
$technical = preg_replace($regex, '$1', $technical);
```

Edit, because of your character is a `xA0` try this:

```
$technical = str_replace("\xc2\xa0",' ',$technical);
```

Comment: xA0 i have this character

Comment: @jujuju post the text in your quesiton, without it I can't help you more

Comment: how do you mean, to paste this text? But i cant paste this character from editor, its always blank ?

Comment: @jujuju you should use a tool that print every single character with its unicode representation or a php function that do that, then post the text